# Must mining pools use the same address?

Tags: mining-pools, address

Must all members of a mining pool use the same address?  Is there ever an exception?

I know nothing of mining pools so can provide more information if possible, but what I mean in specifics is can a mining pool use every member's address in the blocks, or do all members have to use one address in the blocks and be repaid later on trust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your address is not in the blocks being mined.  All of the coins go to the pool operator.  He then takes his cut and divides the rest among the members of the pool.  The pool usually keeps the coins in your mining account until it reaches a payout threshold or you request a manual distribution.  This is done to reduce the number of very small transactions.

So, yes, you have to trust the pool operator.  But all blocks can be viewed on the blockchain, so you can audit the results if necessary.